# Swift getting index out of range error in Tableview while searching and scrolling result

Tags: ios, swift

In myscenario, I am trying to load my JSON data into tableview array and assigning Tableview array to filter array. Here, while searching some time I am getting each and doing scroll to getting crash `index out of range` error. I am loading data from JSON with help of codable.

```
var sections = [Section]()
var filteredSections = [Section]()

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
     return isFiltering ? filteredSections.count : sections.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     let currentSection = isFiltering ? filteredSections[section] : sections[section]
     return currentSection.result.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
      return isFiltering ? filteredSections[section].title : sections[section].title
}

         func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
                let cell:HomeCustomCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as! HomeCustomCell
                let section = isFiltering ? filteredSections[indexPath.section] : sections[indexPath.section]
                let item = section.result[indexPath.row] // getting here error 
                return cell
        }
```

**Search Delegates**

below delegate methods I am using for Searchbar

```
   func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
            isFiltering = true
        }

        func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
            isFiltering = false
        }

        func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
            isFiltering = false
        }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        isFiltering = false
        //filteredSections.removeAll()
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        if searchText == "" {
            print("UISearchBar.text cleared!")
        }
    }

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

        if !searchText.isEmpty {

            if (project_type == "project" || project_type == "test_project"){
                filteredSections = sections.compactMap { section -> Section? in
                    let filteredContent = section.result.filter {($0.project_viewable_id?.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil))
                }
                isFiltering = true

            } else {

                filteredSections = sections.compactMap { section -> Section? in
                    let filteredContent = section.result.filter {($0.task_viewable_id?.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil))
                }
                isFiltering = true
            }
        } else {
            //filteredSections.removeAll()
            isFiltering = false
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: what type of sections is? can you add type and values.

Comment: show us how you are setting number of rows to your tableView

Comment: can you add search logic here.

Comment: @SGDev I have updated my question. Please check it.

Comment: put `let item = section.result[indexPath.row] ` inside if let condition, like `if  let item = section.result[indexPath.row] { code }`. and then run it will not crash you app.

Comment: @SGDev won’t that just hide the real error?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yes I agree that is not a proper solution it will only hide the error.

Comment: Have you debugged this, probably the best way forward. Spontaneously it feels like the bug is caused by isFiltered being incorrect or that you have some issue with your data structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to reload `UITableView` when you change isFiltering `Bool` value.

```
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    isFiltering = true
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    isFiltering = false
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    isFiltering = false
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    isFiltering = false
    //filteredSections.removeAll()
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: `searchBarSearchButtonClicked` here I need to remove `isFiltering = false` and `self.tableView.reloadData()`. because after click keyboard search button the tableview data reloading to showing main array data.

Comment: Yes, you can change according to your requirement but keep in mind when you change Bool value it is necessary to reload table else it will crash.